# Feature request for tracking votes for low rep users

Tags: feature-request, votes

I recently voted on a couple of questions and answers on CrossValidated. As I have 1 rep, my votes are not scored. However, I expected that my votes would show up on my profile action history so I could find the questions and answers I found helpful.

***Joke alert:***
What is the probability that a "voting history for low rep users" feature will be implemented?

Comment: I just gave you +5 rep, hopefully you can post something :-)

Comment: I cannot verify your claim: your user profile on CV shows you have never voted.  Do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: I do not have multiple accounts and have voted with this one.

Comment: @whuber That is the problem I'm bringing up - that I can't track my votes on my profile while I am low rep.

Comment: If you click to vote before you have the privilege to vote, I don't think it ever shows anywhere on your account as a vote. My understanding it it's recorded as if someone with  no account had voted (which does impact some things though isn't worth reputation) but doesn't count for you. (People without an account who click on the upvote arrow get a little thank you message, but it's not dealt with like an upvote)

Comment: If you have below 15 rep, you cannot vote (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Hence this: `I recently voted on a couple of questions and answers on CrossValidated. As I have 1 rep` -- is impossible.

Comment: Are you voting while logged in or not? There are two voting systems: one for guests and another for registered users.

Comment: @Glen_b Hmm, I thought it's not possible to vote without an account. I can't vote on CV if I am not logged in.

Comment: The message I receive when "voting" with less than 15 rep is the following: **"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."** I'd like to see that record listed in my vote history on my profile. Maybe they can automatically count for scores once my rep is high enough.

Comment: @amoeba https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU2EQ.png ... it's not an actual vote.

Comment: @whuber I am voting while logged in.

Comment: @amoeba I agree with Alexander Li's request, irregardless of the action being a vote or not. The 'action' could still be logged for exactly the purpose of being able to find those questions or answers you've liked. IMO it's either that or make clear that to acquire 'history-privileges', you first need a little reputation (i.e. the same 15 points needed to vote).

Comment: @IWS To me it looks like if you have rep<15, *you cannot vote*. Asking to have a log of actions that are not possible is just weird.

Comment: @Glen_b You mentioned that such attempts-to-vote-by-users-below-15rep actually "do impact some things". Do you know & can you tell which things?

Comment: When browsing some questions just now I noticed the 'favorite option' (the nice yellow star). Is that one available for new (low rep) users (I do not really remember)? If so, then I would gladly concede my previous comment and 'side'/agree with @amoeba. If the only purpose is being able to find these question or answers again, this option seems adequate enough.

Comment: -1 based on what I wrote above. I consider this suggestion confusing.

Comment: @IWS I did not notice the favorite option. I will use that. However, perhaps it would be appropriate to turn a non-vote into a vote after someone reaches 15 rep?

Comment: @AlexanderLi that seems reasonable, but you would have to take it up on the main Meta site (and probably not likely to be implemented)

Comment: @ameoba Its my recollection that account-less votes are (or perhaps were) used for something but I don't recall what that actually is.

Answer (score 4):

Low rep users can "favorite" questions in order to keep track of questions that they found useful. Favorite questions are listed separately from votes in the profile history and do not require reputation.

Answers to a specific question cannot be marked as favorite, so revisiting an old question may take a minimal bit of effort to find the desired answer.

Because the "favorite" feature covers the desired use case (allow low rep users to keep track of useful questions and information), though not the exact technical request (track votes for low rep users), I'd guess the probability of implementing this feature request to be pretty low.